# Special characters in file path causing XML XSD validation to fail

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I read a lot of questions here in S.O. about this error, but none seems like the problem I have.

In Eclipse my project is imported through the following path:

> D:\Repositório\branch 7.x.x dev\project-commons

The example.xsd is in the folder `\src\main\resources\schemas\` and contains a tag including another XSD like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.teste.com/abc" targetNamespace="http://www.teste.com/abc" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="layoutBase.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="complexExample" type="CplExmpl">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation> Process...</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Type of `CplExmpl` is defined in layoutBase.xsd.

The layoutBase.xsd is located in the same folder of example.xsd.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.teste.com/abc" targetNamespace="http://www.teste.com/abc" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="CplExmpl">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation> Process...</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element .../>
            <xs:element .../>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="version" .../>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

But when I run my service and validate through example.xsd it does not work.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/Repositório/branch 7.x.x dev/project-commons/target/classes/schemas/example.xsd; 
    lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 45; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'CplExmpl' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:627)
    at javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:659)
    at br.com.oobj.util.xml.JAXPValidate$ValidatorKeyedPoolFactoryAdapter.getSchema(JAXPValidate.java:523)
    at br.com.oobj.util.xml.JAXPValidate$ValidatorKeyedPoolFactoryAdapter.makeObject(JAXPValidate.java:509)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
    at br.com.oobj.util.xml.JAXPValidate.borrowValidator(JAXPValidate.java:212)
    ... 12 more
```

After that, I did a test running in another directory this service. And it work.
Seems like the error is caused by the special character "ó" in D:\Repositório.
The `<xs:include schemaLocation="layoutBase.xsd"/>` is not found.
I test putting the complexType inside example.xsd and it work too.

This happens only in my environment.  It works well in the environment of others on my team.

Has anyone already get a problem like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Reproducing the problem

I can confirm the behavior you report running Xerces-J v2.11.0 under Windows 7.

I've adapted your code below to be a complete example of the problem, including the following particular changes:

1. The XML document use of
   `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.teste.com/abc example.xsd"` to hint
   as to the location of the main XSD.
2. The main XSD's declaration of `xmlns:abc="http://www.teste.com/abc"`
   and its use of the `abc` prefix to reference the type of
   `complexExample` as `abc:CplExmpl`.

### XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<complexExample xmlns="http://www.teste.com/abc"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.teste.com/abc example.xsd"
                version="1">
  <a/>
  <b/>
</complexExample>
```

### Main XSD  (example.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:abc="http://www.teste.com/abc"
           targetNamespace="http://www.teste.com/abc"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:include schemaLocation="layoutBase.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="complexExample" type="abc:CplExmpl">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> Process...</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### Included XSD (layoutBase.xsd):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:abc="http://www.teste.com/abc"
           targetNamespace="http://www.teste.com/abc"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:complexType name="CplExmpl">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation> Process...</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="a"/>
      <xs:element name="b"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="version"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Together, these three documents are correct and will allow the example XML to be validated successfully, *provided no special character exists in the path containing these files.*

If I add a "ó" character to the path containing these files, the parser can no longer find the files *even though only relative paths are being used.*

---

## Potential underlying source of the problem

[The Java URI That Isn't](http://www.garretwilson.com/blog/2008/10/25/javauriclassgotchas.xhtml) suggests describes weakness in Java's [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class's handling of special characters in path names.  Xerces-J may be being bitten by such issues here.

---

## Working around the problem

Specifying **absolute paths using full URI notation** for all files works around the problem:

1. Validate the XML document using `file:///D:/path/to/file.xml`.
2. Specify the location of the main XSD using
   `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.teste.com/abc
   file:///D:/path/to/file/example.xsd"`
3. Specify the location of the included XSD using `<xs:include
   schemaLocation="file:///D:/path/to/file/layoutBase.xsd"/>`.

Making these changes will allow the XML document to be validated against the XSDs even if a special character exists in the path.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of your project open tab "Resource" and select the "Text file encoding" to UTF-8.